# Contributions: Received Date Vs. Completed Date?

Tags: contributions, dates, stripe

This might be a little odd.

A non-profit I work with is having issues with their contribution reports.  They use the stripe extension to process contributions.  They run a search weekly for the past weeks contributions.

They've noticed that if they run the same search again a few days later, there will be more contributions for that same period than there were the first time they ran the search.

We think it might be related to how stripe and civi store contribution dates.  Stripe seems to record the 'date completed' while civi seems to store the date attempted or 'received'.  So a pending contribution through stripe might not pass through to civi until several days after the date that civi records.

Does this make sense or am I overlooking something else that might be causing the inconsistency?